# Regex to replace words and symbols javascript or jquery

Tags: regex, replace

the code is very short and clear, i just want to change the color of body tag with the opening and closing tag < >

can someone explain to me why it does not work? and how to fix it.

```
var newColors = document.getElementById('mainPreTah').innerHTML;
newColors.replace(/<body>/g, "<span style='color:blue'><body></span>");
document.getElementById('mainPreTah').innerHTML = newColors;
```

Comment: Oh God it's this question again. Blah blah, can't parse HTML with regex, blah it will fail with `<body someAttr='<body>'>` or `<head data-foo='<body>'>` or whatever. Blah regular languages and HTML not being regular, blah using a stack. Blah blah DOM API blah built in blah `document.body.style.backgroundColor='blue'` . Blah the center will not hold it is too late. Obligatory link http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1348195 blah. Happy coding!

Comment: OH GOD ZALGO NO! NOOOO!!!!

Comment: Wait, I just realized you have a `<body>` tag in a span tag. Nothing to see here :( Wat.

Comment: You should first learn HTML...

Comment: Wasn't this question asked earlier by the same guy? Or one very similar?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do that. You have to traverse the DOM elements and change properties

Instead of modifiying the html you can change the DOM using the functions that already exists.

For example for this:

```
<body>
  <span id="myspan"></span>
</body>
```

You can do something like to change the color of the span.

```
var mySpan = document.getElementById("myspan");
mySpan.style.color = "blue";
```

There are multiple ways to find elements in html. You should check for those functions:

1. getElementById
2. getElementsByTagName
3. getElementsByClassName
4. getElementsByTagName
5. getElementsByTagName

In your case, you could use

```
   var mySpans = document.getElementsByTagName("span"),
       i;
   for (i=0; i<mySpans.length; i++) {
       mySpans[i].style.color = "blue";
   }
```